# Why my addClass removeClass with event handler does not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery version `1.6`

**Goal:** When a user clicks on down arrow (`expander-down`), show the advanced area. Like wise, when a user clicks on upper arrow (`expander-up`), hide the advanced area.

**Problem:**
I thought it was simple to achieve with the code below. After I click on the `expander-up`, the advanced search area shows up as expected however when I click on `expander-down`, nothing happens.

FYI, I use image splite technique to swap the look of arrow by add/removing classes (expander-down, expander-up).

**javascript:**

```
$(".expander-down").unbind("click").click(function ()
{
   $(this).addClass("expander-up").removeClass("expander-down");
   $("#advanced-search").show();
});

$(".expander-up").unbind("click").click(function ()
{
   $(this).addClass("expander-down").removeClass("expander-up");
   $("#advanced-search").hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href='#'>
  <span class='expander-down'></span>
</a>

<div id='advanced-search'>advanced!</div>
```

Comment: $(this).addClass(".expander-up").removeClass(".expander-down");?

Comment: I think the unbinds are sabotaging your click handler code. Or maybe the fact that you're removing the class that you are selecting the elements with.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ maybe you have  to $(this).removeClass("expander-down").addClass("expander-up");

Comment: I think its the fact that you are removing the class you are binding to. If you give the `a` an id and select bind the click to that you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the elements to which the `click` handlers are assigned are never changed. Even when the user clicks an expander, you leave the same handler (down or up) in place on it.

I would refactor it like this:

```
$(".expander-down, .expander-up").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("expander-down expander-up");
    $("#advanced-search").toggle($this.hasClass("expander-down"));
    return false; // Stops propagation and prevents default action
});
```

That responds to a click by toggling the down/up state, and then shows/hides the search box based on the resulting state. I **think** your code was showing it when the expander was down, so that's what I've done above, but that doesn't immediately make sense to me. If I'm misreading, just change `expander-down` in the `hasClass` to `expander-up`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that `.expander-up` doesn't exist on pageload, meaning that event won't be ever bound to your span.

Unbinding all click functions isn't neccesary at all.
Also, you can merge both functions in one:

```
$(".expander").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // This avoids unwanted scrolling effect
   $(this).toggleClass("expander-up expander-down");
   $("#advanced-search").toggle();
});
```

`toggleClass` adds the css class to the element if it's not already set, and removes the class if it's set.
`toggle` does the same but  for element visibility.

Your html should be like:

```
<a href='#'>
  <span class='expander expander-down'></span>
</a>

<div id='advanced-search'>advanced!</div>
```